# writablebitmap aspect ratio save image

Tags: windows-phone-8, writablebitmap

i'm read a image from PhotoChooserTask and have a stream of a photo.
I have to reduce the size of image

i write this code

```
            WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(400, 400);
            writeableBitmap.LoadJpeg(stream);

            using (var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (isoFile.FileExists("Myfile.jpg")) isoFile.DeleteFile("Myfile.jpg");
                using (var filestream = isoFile.CreateFile("Myfile.jpg"))
                {
                    writeableBitmap.SaveJpeg(filestream, writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, writeableBitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                }
            }
```

this code not keep aspect ration of image.

how to make?

Answer (score 0):

First load the source image to writeableBitmap (without resizing).

Then get the source width (PixelWidth) and full height (PixelHeight). Dividing PixelWidth with PixelHeight will give you the ratio. You can use this value when resizing.

So:

```
float aspectRatio = (float) writeableBitmap.PixelWidth / writeableBitmap.PixelHeight;
```

Then when saving just do

```
writeableBitmap.SaveJpeg(filestream, ResizedWidthValue, (int) ResizedWidthValue / aspectRatio, 0, 100);
```

Comment: WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap();   not is possible.

Comment: Open Nuget and get WriteableBitmapEx. Then use WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = BitmapFactory.New(0,0);

Answer (score 0):

@ertay

i'm write this code

```
using (var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    WriteableBitmap wb = BitmapFactory.New(0, 0);
                    wb.FromStream(isolatedStorage.OpenFile("1.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

                    IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream= isolatedStorage.CreateFile("1_thumb.jpg");

                    float aspectRatio = (float)wb.PixelWidth / wb.PixelHeight;

                    wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, 200, (int) (200 / aspectRatio), 0, 100);

                    fileStream.Close();
                    wb = null;

                }
```

but wb.PixelWidth and wb.PixelHeight = 0!!

Why?